# How to get Full Document from firestore including the reference Data populated

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore in my Swift project. I would like to get all the reference data inside the document populated when I fetch the list. But currently, I only get the reference Ids.

Here is the sample code that I am using to get the list of conversations

```
func getConversationByUserId(createdBy: String, completion: @escaping ([Conversation])->()) {
        let conversationRef = DBHelper.shared.database.collection("conversations")
        let createdByRef = DBHelper.shared.database.document("users/\(createdBy)")
        
        conversationRef
            .whereField("members", arrayContains: createdByRef)
            .addSnapshotListener() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    if querySnapshot!.documents.isEmpty {
                        completion([])
                    } else {
                        var conversations: [Conversation] = []
                        if let snaps = querySnapshot?.documents {
                            for item in snaps {
                                conversations.append(Conversation(snapshot: item))
                            }
                        }
                        completion(conversations)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Help me understand `whereField("members", arrayContains: createdByRef`. You want to query a collection for documents that have an array that contains a document reference?

Comment: yes. But also I want the other document reference to be populated. For example, createdBy should be populated with the user object instead of just reference id. In short like mongoose populate function

Comment: Is the problem getting the documents or is the problem converting the documents into `Conversation` objects?

Comment: I am getting documents. The problem is in thee sample I provided, everything is reference id. I want to each of those as object. For example, in the image i provided, createdBy is returning an id, instead I want the actual user object there

Comment: You have to either get that document using the reference or include the user information in this document.

Comment: what is the best practice here?

Comment: Both are acceptable. It depends on the architecture of your data in Firestore, cost, and personal preference. If you include the user data in this document, then every time user data is updated then you will need to find every document that contains this user data and update those documents as well. If, instead, you do a separate document get right here then you won't have to update multiple user documents but will have to make 2 reads instead of 1. Weigh the $ cost of both scenarios. And also weigh the complexity cost; I try to avoid complexity as much as I can even at the cost of $.

Comment: The act of duplicating data in NoSQL architecture (i.e. Firestore) is called denormalization is a very powerful and common tool. But it can get out of hand, depending on how much data there is to duplicate and how popular it is (i.e. how often it's updated versus read). Only someone who really knows your database layout will be able to make the right decision here.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is a NoSQL database, we need to switch our coding mind from SQL database.

I would recommend to either store all related information in one document or you can fetch all needed information with multiple calls.

If you want to simplify the front-end logic, you can consider use Firebase Cloud Function to take over the multiple fetching logic.